# Android program writes to emulator but not phone

Tags: java, android

I am trying to write an Android program to accept input and then write the data to a file on the internal storage of my phone. When I execute my program on the emulator it makes a file just as I expect it to, but when I try and execute it on my phone the file doesn't seem to be created. I've looked around on this site and I can't seem to find a solution to my problem anywhere (a few similar ones, but nothing that worked for me) I was hoping you guys might be able to offer me advice on what I'm doing wrong.

```
FileOutputStream fos = null;
String x = "Sample String";
    try{
            fos = openFileOutput("answers.txt", MODE_PRIVATE);
            fos.write(x.getBytes());

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }    

    try {
           fos.close();
         } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

On the emulator, I can find the file in DDMS at "data/data/com.example.helloandroid/files/answers.txt". On the phone, if I try to open up the data folder in DDMS it shows it is an empty directory. I have already added in this line to my manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I cannot seem to think of anything else that I could be doing wrong. Thanks in advance for the help, it is appreciated.

Comment: You can't access your internal directory of your phone unless you root it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is fine, but like others have said DDMS in Eclipse does not have the proper access to the internal storage, which is where /data/data lives.  You can find a reference to the different types of Android storage at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

One way to get access is to root your device.

Another way is to install a userdebug build.

The easiest way however is via the undocumented `run-as` option of [adb](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html).  This allows you to access files owned by your app, even if they are in internal storage.

To verify that the file you are interested in is being created, type in at the command line:

```
adb shell run-as com.example.helloandroid ls -l /data/data/com.example.helloandroid/files/
```

To get the contents of a specific file, type in, also at the command line:

```
adb shell run-as com.example.helloandroid cat /data/data/com.example.helloandroid/files/answers.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything is Right with your code , the only Reason you can not see the file in your phone is : Your Phone is not Root! Root your phone and then Just use RootExplorer (or any other app) too see your result in the same directory as emulator ! beside this why dont print the text? to ensure that your file is created after fos.close() add bufferReader and try to put the data into String and then Print it! then you can see the result in LogCat